# Ignore specific path in Gatsby cache

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I have a Gatsby application that is partially static and has some routes that must be handled by Nginx instead of Gatsby service worker, but still didn't find a way to remove a specific path from Gatsby cache. Consider the following pages:

- `/home` *alright, handled by Gatsby*
- `/contact` *alright, handled by Gatsby*
- `/blog`*handled by Nginx*

My home page has a link for `/blog`, that stands under the same domain, but Nginx is responsible for providing its content, so I don't have a Gatsby page for it.

The problem arises because sometimes when clicking in the *Blog* link, then the service worker will send me to a 404 page, but some other times it will just work fine.

I've already tried to add the `blog/`path to the `navigateFallbackWhitelist` of `gatsby-plugin-offline`, but still had no success.

Is there a way to force Gatsby to permanently ignore and **not** cache a specific path?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Gatsby separately for home and contact.
Will that be alright?

[check this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)